How to use absolute imports of folders inside any app with nx monorepo
I'm migrating my company frontend project to a mono-repo with Nx mono-repo tool, and have the following structures -
apps/pay-platform - where our main app exists.
packages/sk-ui - design system.
Now, in my existing react+vite project I have several folders like helper, component, api, and modules, and we were using absolute imports like import ( getDate ) from 'helpers'; earlier.
But now, this is not working in a mono-repo setup.
Inside apps/pay-platform/tsconfig.app.json I have updated the baseUrl and paths config -
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
    }
  },
  ...
}


Along with this, I also installed vite-tsconfig-paths and used it in apps/pay-platform/vite.config.ts like
import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

...
plugins: [react(), nxViteTsPaths(), viteTsconfigPaths()],
...

Now, inside apps/pay-platform/src/app/app.tsx, I'm able to use import { consoleLog } from 'helper'; but other package imports are not working, which were defined in root level tsconfig.base.json like import { Button } from '@skuad/sk-ui';
this is root level tsconfig.base.json -
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@skuad/fe-core": ["packages/fe-core/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/fe-utils": ["packages/fe-utils/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/sk-ui": ["packages/sk-ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/ui-components": ["packages/ui-components/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  ...
}



I can modify the root level tsconfig.base.json to enable absolute imports for internal folders too, but this is not recommended as you'll get the error of something like - Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project

after struggling enough and playing with tsconfig + vite configuration. I have found a solution.
So, inside our app, we need to do a few things.
First, install vite-tsconfig-paths and update apps/pay-platform/vite.config.ts as below -
// apps/pay-platform/vite.config.ts
...
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({ 
 ...
 plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths()],
 ...
})
...

Then, inside apps/pay-platform/tsconfig.app.json, we will set new baseUrl, and paths, that will eventually override global base values present inside tsconfig.base.json
// apps/pay-platform/vite.config.ts
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@skuad/fe-core": ["../../packages/fe-core/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/fe-utils": ["../../packages/fe-utils/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/sk-ui": ["../../packages/sk-ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@skuad/ui-components": ["../../packages/ui-components/src/index.ts"],
      "@pay/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
}


This way, we're overriding tsconfig.base.json -  baseUrl, and paths and adding our own absolute paths. And to compile this vite-tsconfig-paths is going to come into the picture.
And, finally, to let other packages/libraries also work in our app we will add those too inside our app level ts-config (apps/pay-platform/tsconfig.app.json).
